# HF and water miscible?

Tags: aqueous-solution

According to Wikipedia, HF is miscible with water. But isn't hydrogen fluoride a gas at RT and a sensible pressure? What would happen if you just kept adding more HF gas to some water?

Answer (score 6):

Aqueous hydrofluoric acid of commerce is 48 wt-% HF, which averages tight to hydronium fluoride, $\ce{H3O^+ F^-}$.  You can snug 100% HF as $\ce{3 HF}$ being in equilibrium with $\ce{H2F^+ + {FHF}^{−}}$.  However, there is no concentration of HF that will separate into two liquid phases or a solid phase with solution at ambient temperature and pressure.

Hydrofluoric acid is exceptionally aggressive and lethal toward tissue by contact.  Effects can be delayed but not reversed.  Topical or infused calcium gluconate can ameliorate further damage.

Comment: What do "averages tight" and "snug" mean in this context? Also, does this really answer his question?

Comment: @Cohen_the_Librarian The answer gives information on the dissociation of hydrogen fluoride in water, describes further species characteristic for HF (and not found for HCl and HBr) and provides a well-meant health warning for less-experienced participants. If this is not an answer, what would be a better answer you would give?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha The health warning is well appreciated. However, the vocabulary questions I raise are because those phrases are incomprehensible to me and Google does not provide any top listing with those words + "chemistry". As a result of that incomprehensibility, I doubted the OP's ability to understand either (perhaps too much of an assumption). The next reason for my comment is that the OP's question of "What would happen if you just kept adding HF?" is not clearly answered. Perhaps it should read: "The continuous addition of HF will..." (I don't know exactly how to answer at this point).

Comment: @Cohen_the_Librarian I see the product of both autoionization and homoassociation of HF at high concentrations (when remaining water becomes just a trace) clearly mentioned.

Comment: Uncle Al is a make believe James Joyce. HF in water is not a solution it is a reaction and cannot be treated as a molecular solution. Also the equilibria usually involve the gas phase. The health warnings are a nonsequitor.

Answer (score 4):

> But isn't hydrogen fluoride a gas at RT and a sensible pressure?

Actually, it depends on the room in question. $HF$ boils at 19.5 C, meaning one can check if it mixes well with chill water or at relatively hight pressure.

> What would happen if you just kept adding more $HF$ gas to some water?

Learn about binary diagrams (thermodynamic chemistry) and  find one for $HF/H_2O $ system

Answer (score -3):

> HF is miscible with water. But isn't hydrogen fluoride a gas at RT and a sensible pressure? What would happen if you just kept adding more HF gas to some water?

HF vapors miscible in water due to Hydrogen bonding due to Which HF make azeotropic mixture with water.